# Why isnt this jquery working? Jquery Character Count

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' />
<div class='counter' style='margin:0; padding:0;'> </div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#addComment').each(function(){
                // get current number of characters
                var length = $(this).val().length;
                // get current number of words
                //var length = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
                // update characters
                $(this).parent().find('.counter').html( 254 - length + ' characters left');
                // bind on key up event
                $(this).keyup(function(){
                    // get new length of characters
                    var new_length = $(this).val().length;
                    // get new length of words
                    //var new_length = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
                    // update
                    $(this).parent().find('.counter').html( 254 - new_length + ' characters left');
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/7d7mB/).

You probably want to know how to limit it once it exceeds the limitation.

Just do this...

```
$(this).val(function(index, oldValue) { return oldValue.substring(0, 254); })
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d7mB/1/).

Comment: This still does not work. does putting this in a php echo statement like 'echo "<img src='img/commentBelowIcon.png' width='26' height='26' class='left' /><h3>Add Comment</h3>
    <input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' />
    <div class='counter' style='margin:0; padding:0;'> </div>   
    ";' mess it up?

Comment: @woopie It shouldn't. Check the fiddle.

Comment: I had checked the fiddle and still got the exact same problem.

Comment: @woopie Care to explain the problem? Your post just has code and *does not work* is generally too vague to be useful. You should give as much information as possible when you ask a question, such as errors received, problems encountered, etc.

Comment: Alex - that's just it, its as if nothing has changed on page.